# Ubuntu 18.04 new user, needs help

Tags: networking, mount, internet, files, deb

Have a need for a home file server, I am new to Linux and have decided on working with Ubuntu 18.04.  Downloaded and installed Ubuntu 18.04.  The server is "running" but I can't seem to get off square 1.  Server is running on a fresh build w/a 2TB sata drive.  This is not a dual boot machine Ubuntu is the only sw loaded.  The PC has a Ethernet port and a wireless card.  The Ethernet is an intranet (no internet access) the wireless is the internet access point.  Even though the server is running it has no internet access. Had trouble finding anything out about the status of the wireless card.  Every time i would try a Linux command,  RFKILL, wireless tools, wpasupplicant none of the commands were not found.  Cannot use the apt command without internet access.  Have been trying to download the deb files as needed, and moving to the server via a USB flash drive.  Very limited success mounting and unmounting a USB drive.  The USB mount and umount went great the first time.  Have not been able to access the USB drive on the server since.  The USB drive is readable on a windows machine.  Tried to reformat the USB to different formats, the final attempt was NTFS.  The USB drive remains unreadable in Ubuntu.  Searched and searched on "new to Ubuntu", just cant seem to find anything there that seems close to my problems.  This Linux is a new world for me, is it really necessary that i have to keep going and getting all these deb files, or are they really available in this install of Ubnutu and I'm not smart enough to find them?

Do have a Win 10 machine on the intranet that I looked briefly into setting up it as a shared internet connection, that sounds like more work than downloading deb files.....  However it is becoming very apparent that internet access is mission critical !!!  Am still willing to consider and pursue this option, but frankly don't know where to start.

I'm not a network wizzard, but have done some basic networking.  Also am not opposed to doing online research to find answers, just can't seem to find any solutions :-(  Am hoping that I am missing something that might make the building and start up of this Unbuntu server doable.  I've been at this for a couple weeks and don't feel like i'm getting anywhere, appreciate any help, advice, or guidance.....

Thanks in advance for anyone's help !!!

Comment: Which Ubuntu 18.04 LTS did you install, you mention you want it to be a file server, so does that mean you installed Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS?  Most servers don't usually have wifi, but did you get very far with the wifi troubleshooting documentation? (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide) where the device recognition link is most useful, as it'll let you know what chipset/device you have allowing searching online, or providing details for us to assist you.

Comment: Yes, sorry i did install  Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS.  My problem is that all the "tools" wireless-tools, wpasuppliciant i need to use need for troubleshooting/setup appear to need to be downloaded and installed via .deb file?  Is this correct or are they with this installation and I can't find them?  Also struggling with mounting a usb flash drive that i'm trying to use to get the .deb files.

Comment: OK just tried the first command in the wifi trouble shooting documentation nm-tool, and I get the typical reply from Unbuntu Command 'nm-tool' not found, did you mean : .....  I also tried nm -tool, same message.  It just seems like every command I type per the instructions I get a "not found".  Is it me or ?????

Comment: Look up how to use "netplan" to set up your wireless network access. Creating the correct file is very easy, and lots of examples are available online. NetworkManager is for machines with a desktop (not you). /etc/network/interfaces is the old way, superseded by netplan.

Comment: From my prior link I was trying to allude to step 1 device recognition link, which doesn't require the use of `nm-tool`, ie. it sends you to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide/Devices ..  You can copy files by USB as I do it, but you mention vague things like "*remains unreadable in Ubuntu*" where had you provided your command and the resulting error message we could see & reply to your issue, but its possible as I do it (I could guess`ntfs-3g` but I can't see messages). If you want to provide more detail, edit your question and place it there please.

Comment: Used the same commands that worked fine the first time:
sudo fdsik -l (to get the device sdb number, sdb1 which never seems to change)
sudo mkdir /media/usb (also tried to use a different name usb1)
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /media/usb uid=xxxxx ( xxxx is the user name)
when finished with usb drive
sudo umount /media/usb (after this command all I saw was the prompt at the next line, never received any message is that normal?

The above commands work perfect the first time.  

Now i get messages like wrong fs type , bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1, USB is readable on Win 10

Comment: From device recognition lshw -c network command it sees both the wireless card and the ethernet card,  it starts with * network DISABLED for the wireless adapter.   Thinking I need the wireless-tools to setup the wireless network name and password.  Is that right or am i off in the weeds, again ?

Comment: Disabled typically means that the wireless switch or key combination is set to disable the wireless radio. Is this a laptop? wpa-supplicant is required but not installed by default in the server addition of Ubuntu. I suggest that you download and install it before we proceed.

Comment: Agree 100% and have downloaded wpasupplicant and wireless-tools but can't get it from the USB flash drive to the server.  Please see the comments above about Ubuntu can't read the USB drive that appears fine on a Win 10 machine.  The USB drive worked fine the fist time, haven't been able to get it or any usb flash stick to work with Ubuntu, that's where I'm stuck...

Comment: I suggest that the USB key be formatted fat32.

Comment: Will try FAT 32 on the USB drive and see how that goes.  Any other suggestions for this to try?  The tower does have a CD/DVD drive am considering using it for file transfer.  Anyone ever use a CD/DVD drive to transfer files to a Ubuntu server?  Thanks !!!

Comment: You can certainly use a CD/DVD drive but remember that the files will be on the CD as read-only. When you copy them to your home directory, make them read, write and executable: `sudo chmod +wx some.deb`

Comment: Great point!!   Thank you